# casperjs cant click popup

Tags: popup, casperjs

My code:

```
casper.waitForSelector('.single_like_button.btn3-wrap .btn3',
   function success() {
       this.click('.single_like_button.btn3-wrap .btn3');
   }
);
```

Returned:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.angular.version')

  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vfl2odRpD/angular_base.js:167
  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vfl2odRpD/angular_base.js:225
```

the button when clicked, will open a second tab window, like a popup,
when the second window finished its works, it will close automatically and transfer data back to 1st window.
I dont know if this process had used angular js?
and do i need to install angularjs and how?
beacuse the error seemed related to angularjs

the popup url is inside a javascript's function, i dont know how to scrape it
I dont get the popup url, so i dont know how to use "waitforpopup"
but even if i can get the url, i still have to click the button in order to the correct data transfer. I have used clickLabel("Subscribe", div) , also not working.

Any advices?

Comment: Please let the community know if you fix this

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with `waitForSelector` before.. Although I'm not familiar with your html/js, why not try the following in place of your code above to do a quick sanity check. This will give you a better idea of what's happening.

```
this.wait(5000,function(){ // use wait (5 secs) instead of waitForSelector

    // log the el to see if it exists at this point 
    console.log($('.single_like_button.btn3-wrap .btn3').length + " els found");

    // click dat
    this.click('.single_like_button.btn3-wrap .btn3');

});
```